# Jeet grid broken

Tags: html, css, jeet-grid

My first question here. 
I'm trying to make a simple gallery grid using jeet, but the final result is all broken up. It skips some divs to the next row, and I just can't find a way to control it.

```css
.row.nossos-parceiros
 background-color #EFEAE4
 margin auto
 h2
  text-align center
  padding-bottom 1em
 .parceiro 
  col(1/4, gutter: 1, cycle: 5)
  margin-bottom:@margin-right;
  height:220px;
  background:white
  text-align:center
  
  &:hover
   text-decoration:none
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 37px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 37px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   box-shadow: 0px 4px 37px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

```html
<div class="row nossos-parceiros">
   <div class="container">
   <h2>Nossos Parceiros</h2>
   <div class="parceiro"></div>
   <div class="parceiro"></div>
   <div class="parceiro"></div>
   <div class="parceiro"></div>
   <div class="parceiro"></div>
   <div class="parceiro"></div>
   <div class="parceiro"></div>
   <div class="parceiro"></div>
   <div class="parceiro"></div>      
   </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]